# Can't manage to update raspberry pi, gpio-header html file

Tags: javascript, html, raspberry-pi, gpio, webiopi

I'm very new to programming with webiopi and very new to the raspberry pi in general.
Me and my brother are planning to build a robot running on a raspbery pi. We're planning to build a camera on the robot. We would stream the camera through our raspberry pi and controll the robot, both through the same website.

However, here's my problem: I downloaded and installed webiopi for my raspberry pi. And with that webiopi comes an example code which he will execute. These are simple html files. If i make any change to them the raspberry pi just shows the original file.

Here's the first original:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content = "width = 420, user-scalable = no" />
            <title>Webiopi</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            webiopi().ready(function() {
                    webiopi().RPiHeader().createTable("content");
                    w().refreshGPIO(true);
            });
            </script> 
</head> 
<body>
<div id="content" align="center"></div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the version I want to upload(for a test):

```
              <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
     <html>  
     <head>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
             <meta name="viewport" content = "width = 420, user-scalable = no" />
             <title>Webiopi</title>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript">
             webiopi().ready(function() {
                     webiopi().RPiHeader().createTable("content");
                     w().refreshGPIO(true);
             });
             </script> 
     </head> 
     <body>

     <P>Testesttestest</p> 
     <div id="content" align="center">   
     <img width="300" height="240" src="http://raspberrypi:8080/?action=strem"><br/>

     </div> 
     </body>
     </html>
```

I don't know if any of you guys ever had this problem. But I can't continue my project if i can't update my webpage.

Thanks for u're help

Justin

Comment: have you tried an hard refresh (with no cache)? Are you sure you're editing the right file?

Comment: Yeah checked it both. rebooted my rasp and made sure it was the right file. My brother confirmed it :/

Comment: Would you suggest me to just right a new code in stead of editting this one?

Comment: No I would suggest you that you check again the file you edited. I'm not familiar with webiopi but from what I can read in the help files, you should store the files in the `htdocs`of your localserver. (if you use apache, it might be `/var/www/`). If you can wait until tomorrow, I'll test it with my own.

Comment: Hi checked it again. The file is in the directory htdocs and then in the directory gtio-header. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not editing the right files.
Webiopi installs a server on your Raspi. From a fresh install, files are stored in `/usr/share/webiopi/htdocs/`.
Also, you should check this page about [configuration file](https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/wiki/CONFIGURATION) in order to modify the default folder the files are stored in, and other usefull config features.

Comment: Thanks man, you solved my problem. seems like I was editing the wrong file indeed. I was editing the index.html file stored in: /home/pi/WebIOPi-0.7.0/htdocs/ . Thanks for your help and time. I feel kind of noob for a mistake like this. But at least you helped me solve it :)